# Console output not being redirected to file

Tags: c#, cmd, console, command-prompt

I have a Visual studio project that also supports command line. In some part of code(.cs file) we use **Console.WriteLine(message)** to write the results to console.

When I run my project's **.exe** from command prompt, I can see output on command prompt. But when I try

> **app.exe > c:\output.txt**

I cannot find the output in text file. Text file is being created but it is empty. I also tried `app.exe > c:\output.txt 2>&1` but the result is same.
So how can I redirect these output that is displayed on command prompt to a file.

Comment: Is this windows cmd or powershell? Does your account have write access in that directory? When you use the redirection, is the data not being printed to the console?

Comment: It is a window cmd. I have the write access. In fact file is being created but its empty. When I use redirection, data is being printed to console.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using Console.Erroe.WriteLine? Could you post some more code?

Comment: No. I am sure I am using Console.WriteLine(message). I am not sure what more code I can provide you with. And yes we have to provide some arguments so the actual command is `app.exe -arg1 -arg2  >> file.txt`